# When object variable is reassigned in C++, what happens to the original object?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, stack

When an object variable is reassigned in C++, what happens to the original value?
In the code below an object is created onto the stack and placed in *variable*. Then a new object is created on the stack and placed in the same variable. What happens to the original object? Does it stay on the stack until *variable* goes out of scope?

```
void foo() {
    ClassName variable(a, b); // variable created on the stack
    variable = ClassName(c, d); // new value for variable created on stack
    ...
}
```

Comment: Usually, all that happens is that the original object gets modified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What happens is that the class's assignment operator is called.  In most cases that just means that the contents of the old object are updated with values from the new object.  So if `ClassName` is:

```
struct ClassName
{
    int a;
    int b;

    ClassName(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
};
```

In this case the default assignment operator would be called which would be equivalent to:

```
    ClassName& operator=(const ClassName& other)
    {
        a = other.a;
        b = other.b;
        return *this;
    }
```

For classes that have dynamic content there would be a bit more to do, but the results will generally be the same.  Since the assignment operator can be overridden, anything could theoretically happen but this is what we expect.

Answer (score 4):

Technically the `operator=` is invoked by the left hand side part of the assignement, such as

```
variable.operator=(ClassName(c,d));
```

In your case, if you don't explicitly define the assignment operator, the compiler generates a default one for you, which copies the right hand side using the copy assignment operators of its individual members. So the left hand side (i.e., `variable` in your case) is modified, and its individual members are copies of the members of the right hand side temporary.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, nothing happens to the object: *you're still using it*!

Assignment doesn't replace the entire object with a different object: it invokes that original object's assignment operator, allowing the object to make it look like something new, even though it's not.

For example:

```
int x = 1;
x = 2;
```

You have only declared *one* object here, even though its value changes.

Of course there are indeed multiple objects in play in even this simple snippet — both the `1` and the `2` are integer literals and temporary objects. However, it is not these that you have asked about. Their value is copied into `x`.

Similarly, in your own code you copy the "value" of the temporary `ClassName(c, d)` into `variable`, but `variable` is still the original `variable`.

The temporary `ClassName(c, d)` goes out of scope at the end of the line in which you've used it; the bytes used to represent it (unless optimised out) will probably reside within the stack frame until you leave the function scope, though you will not legally be able to read them.